# Open "chrome://" URLs from command line (OSX)

Tags: macos, command-line, google-chrome

I can open regular URLs with `open https://superuser.com` and `open -a "Google Chrome.app" https://superuser.com` but this doesn't work for `chrome://` urls, e.g.

```
$ open -a "Google Chrome.app" chrome://bookmarks
The file /Users/andreas/chrome:/bookmarks does not exist.
```

How do you open `chrome://` URLs from the command line on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

[chrome-cli](https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli) might work:

```
chrome-cli open <url>  (Open url in new tab)
chrome-cli open <url> -n  (Open url in new window)
chrome-cli open <url> -i  (Open url in new incognito window)
chrome-cli open <url> -t <id>  (Open url in specific tab)
chrome-cli open <url> -w <id>  (Open url in new tab in specific window)
```